# Errors on accessing mongodb atlas through create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, create-react-app, mongodb-atlas

I am using the standard connection suggested by mongodb atlas

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-4azjv.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

I am receiving the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at matchesParentDomain (uri_parser.js:30)
at uri_parser.js:71
```

I have included `0.0.0.0/0` in my whitelist.

Comment: How did you pass the username and password to uri?

Comment: through this line "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-4azjv.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

Comment: Do you exactly replace <username> and <password> ?

Comment: Yes, I'm more used to python, and I just use the same string as I would do in python

Comment: Try to put hardcode username and password

Comment: I am currently hardcoding it (unless I'm misunderstanding) "mongodb+srv://awef:abcd@cluster0-4azjv.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem but I couldn't make it, do you have any sandbox or GitHub repo?

Comment: Thanks Alex, I chose to go another way with this. see below

Comment: which mongodb node driver you are using?

Comment: if it's 2.2.12 or later your have to use link like this mongodb://jualahmed:<password>@cluster0-shard-00-00-p5f9f.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-p5f9f.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-p5f9f.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority

Answer (score 0):

The more I looked into this it seems like the distinction between front and back end is a big deal. I encountered a similar problem for `bigquery`. Since I did not want to make a back end, I created a `google cloud function` that serves as a back end and used `fetch`. This also worked for `bigquery`.